# customise the invoice save option

Tags: magento-2.2.5, create-invoice, customize

I want to allow the invoice save action once the order is in processing state for this i have to add some logics inside the Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice save file. please advice me

Comment: please provide the code you want to add. easiest way is probably a observer or a plugin

Comment: @PhilippSander thank you so much for your reply.. i done with the plugin only. i made a mistake in preference type. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

etc/di.xml

create a file for this xx\yy\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Save.php
inside the save.php file write your own logic.

Comment: can you please share your code ?